# Nginx 502 bad gateway error when deploying django; (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, vps, http-status-code-502

I'm trying to set up a VPS Django server with nginx, however, I'm running into a 502 Bad Gateway error when I reload the nginx server with the following settings:

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/project

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domainname.com;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location /static/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/static;
        }
        location /media/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/static;
        }
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock;
        }
}
```

I execute the commands in this order

> sudo nginx -t

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

> sudo ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

> sudo systemctl restart nginx

> sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'

If I exclude `domainname.com` from the `server_name`, then it responds with the classic "Welcome to nginx!" page, however, if I leave it, it responds with "502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)".

I'm clueless as to what I'm supposed to do, any help?

> sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2021/08/17 14:44:42 [crit] 45521#45521: *4 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: (CLIENTHOST), server: (SERVERHOST), request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock:/", host: "(DOMAINNAME).com"
```

**EDIT**
gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Status of both active services:

nginx:

```
ubuntu@vps-bdd44ecc:~$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-08-17 14:13:08 UTC; 9s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 44170 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 44181 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 44186 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 2272)
     Memory: 4.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─44186 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             └─44187 nginx: worker process
```

gunicorn:

```
ubuntu@vps-bdd44ecc:~$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-08-17 14:13:08 UTC; 16s ago
   Main PID: 44192 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 2272)
     Memory: 91.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─44192 /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock project.wsgi:application
             ├─44221 /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock project.wsgi:application
             ├─44225 /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock project.wsgi:application
             └─44231 /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock project.wsgi:application

Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[31290]: [2021-08-17 14:13:08 +0000] [31290] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Succeeded.
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc systemd[1]: Stopped gunicorn daemon.
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[44192]: [2021-08-17 14:13:08 +0000] [44192] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[44192]: [2021-08-17 14:13:08 +0000] [44192] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock (44192)
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[44192]: [2021-08-17 14:13:08 +0000] [44192] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[44221]: [2021-08-17 14:13:08 +0000] [44221] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 44221
Aug 17 14:13:08 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[44225]: [2021-08-17 14:13:08 +0000] [44225] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 44225
Aug 17 14:13:09 vps-bdd44ecc gunicorn[44231]: [2021-08-17 14:13:09 +0000] [44231] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 44231
```

> etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Is your gunicorn server really configured to use SSL? You could try `proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Slide-Hackers-Web/src/project.sock;` instead.

Comment: Where do you suggest I include the proxy_pass? In gunicorn.service? (added in edit) Because I believe it's already in nginx config

Comment: I suggested to exchange `https` with `http` in your nginx config.

Comment: Oh apologies, couldn't see the change, will try

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work @slauth